# Keycloak user storage SPI, not listing users in keycload admin console

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-spi

I have created a user storage SPI, exactly as defined in the documentation: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi, a literal copy/paste.

I have implemented the interface `UserQueryProvider` correctly, but when I go to the admin console in `kecloak, Manage -> Users -> View all users`, only internal db users are displayed, I would expect to see also here my federated users, because I have implemented the `getUsers` method. I added some logs, and none of the `getUsers` overloaded methods is ever called.

However, when I search in the same screen for one of my federated users, it shows up, so the `searchForUser` method from the same interface (`UserQueryProvider`) at least works.

Any idea why?

Regards

[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe someone can help you if you share your SPI code?

Comment: I have the impression that this feature is not supported, even if the documentation says otherwise, because none of official SPI providers support it, such  the LDAP one https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/federation/ldap/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/ldap/LDAPStorageProvider.java#L322

Comment: I have the same problem, Did you find the solution?

Comment: v21.0.2: in this version in the admin console you enter "\*" to view all users, so once I added support for a "\*" search parameter in searchForUserStream() in my SPI, it showed all federated users correctly

Comment: I have the same issue: the list of users does not show by default when I'm using my Spi. I need to perform a search to initiate the search action ? any solution to list all users !